# To have variables and class of variables as new dataset

Tags: r

I have a data frame df below

```
        df
        A   B   C  D   E  F
 1     asd 29  sf 36  sf 44
 2     fsd 24 gfd 56 gfd 34
 3      gs 46 asd 39 asd 37
 4     asd 50 gfg 26 gfg 23
 5      sf 43  fg 56  fg 37
 6     dfg 29  er 35  er 51
 7    sdfg 32  tr 27  tr 28
```

I need to have a new dataset with variable and class of variables as values like below

```
    df1
    COl1   COl2
    A     factor
    B     numeric
    C     factor
    D     numeric
    E     factor
    F     numeric
```

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to get the `class` for each column with `summarise_all` and then `gather` into 'long' format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    summarise_all(class) %>%
    gather
# key   value
#1   A  factor
#2   B numeric
#3   C  factor
#4   D numeric
#5   E  factor
#6   F numeric
```

---

Or with `map/enframe`

```
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
map(df, class) %>% 
        enframe %>%
        unnnest
```

---

Or in `base R`, use `lapply` to get the column class and `stack` the `list` output to a two column data.frame

```
stack(lapply(df, class))[2:1]
#  ind  values
#1   A  factor
#2   B numeric
#3   C  factor
#4   D numeric
#5   E  factor
#6   F numeric
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(A = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 5L), .Label = c("asd", 
"dfg", "fsd", "gs", "sdfg", "sf"), class = "factor"), B = c(29, 
24, 46, 50, 43, 29, 32), C = structure(c(6L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 
2L, 7L), .Label = c("asd", "er", "fg", "gfd", "gfg", "sf", "tr"
), class = "factor"), D = c(36, 56, 39, 26, 56, 35, 27), E = structure(c(6L, 
4L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 7L), .Label = c("asd", "er", "fg", "gfd", 
"gfg", "sf", "tr"), class = "factor"), F = c(44, 34, 37, 23, 
37, 51, 28)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"
), class = "data.frame")
```